# Multiplying field value with retrieved value jQuery

Tags: jquery

I pull product price from another page. Then I multiply it with quantity entered in the quantity input field. The problem is, if I forget to enter quantity value before I pull product price data or if I change the quantity field later, the final total price is not updated. I hope I clearly explained it.

javascript:

```
$('#AddProduct').click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var adding = $(+(i++)+'<div class="row'+(i)+'"><div class="column width50"><input type="text" id="PRODUCTNAME" name="PRODUCTNAME'+(i)+'" value="" class="width98" /><input type="hidden" class="PRODUCTID" name="PRODUCTID" /><input type="hidden" class="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE'+(i)+'" /><small>Search Products</small></div><div class="column width20"><input type="text" class="UNITQUANTITY" name="UNITQUANTITY'+(i)+'" value="" class="width98" /><small>Quantity</small></div><div class="column width30"><span class="prices">Unit Price:<span class="UNITPRICE"></span><br />Total Price:<span class="TOTALPRICE"></span><br /><a href="#" id="RemoveProduct(".row'+(i)+'");">Remove</a></span></div>');    
    $('#OrderProducts').append(adding);

    adding.find("#PRODUCTNAME").autocomplete("orders.cs.asp?Process=ListProducts", {
        selectFirst: false
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        if (data) {
            adding.find(".UNITPRICE").html(data[1]);
            adding.find(".PRODUCTID").val(data[2]);
            adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").html(data[1] * $('.UNITQUANTITY').val()); 
        }
    });

    return false;
});

$('#RemoveProduct').click(function() {
    $().remove();

    return false;
});
```

my html:

```
        <fieldset>
            <h2>Order Items</h2>
            <div id="OrderProducts">
                <a href="#" id="AddProduct"><img src="icons/add.png" alt="Add" /></a>
            </div>  
        </fieldset>
```

- edit

Now I totally messed it up. Removing a row is not working anymore as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 $('input.UNITQUANTITY').blur(function() {
     var $column = $(this).closest('div.column');
     var unit = $column.find('.UNITPRICE').html();
     $column.find('.TOTALPRICE').html(unit * $(this).val());
 });
```

I'm not sure how your HTML is setup so you might need different traversing techniques, but the idea remains the same (update the field whenever unit quantity changes).

Comment: Actually, I thought about but since users can add multiple field sets, (PRODUCTNAME1, UNITQUANTITY1, UNITPRICE1, PRODUCTNAME2, UNITQUANTITY2, UNITPRICE2, PRODUCTNAME3, UNITQUANTITY3, UNITPRICE3) it did not work. I just deactivated password protection. Here is the test link:
http://refinethetaste.com/html/cp/?Section=orders&Process=AddOrder

Comment: I updated the code to account for multiple inputs according to the HTML

Comment: Hi again,
I tried with updated codes, no error but not working either. you can try it yourself as well.

Comment: if the problem is with rebinding, live() could be the solution

Answer (score 0):

for the remove link you could try this:

```
<a href="#"  id="row'+i+'");" class="remove">Remove</a></span>
```

```
$('a.remove').live('click',function() {
     $('div.'+$(this).attr('id')).remove();
});
```